# haskell, how to convert POSIXTime type to a string

Tags: haskell, types

```
Prelude> import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX (getPOSIXTime)
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> ptime <- getPOSIXTime
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> ptime
1360059876.245525s
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX> :t ptime
ptime :: Data.Time.Clock.POSIX.POSIXTime
Prelude Data.Time.Clock.POSIX>
```

I want convert ptime to string type, how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `posixSecondsToUTCTime`, also in Data.Time.Clock.POSIX, to convert the `POSIXTime` to a `UTCTime`; then [`formatTime`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/time-1.4.0.1/Data-Time-Format.html#v%3aformatTime) from Data.Time.Format to format the `UTCTime` into a `String`.

e.g.

```
formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T" (posixSecondsToUTCTime ptime)
-- ^ ISO 8601
formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%s%Qs" (posixSecondsToUTCTime ptime)
-- ^ fractional seconds since the epoch (but see caveat noted in documentation)
```

(`defaultTimeLocale` is from System.Locale.)

Comment: Thanks, you answer works. But if I want get "1360059876.245525s" as a string, how can I do it?